# Internal server error new object php

Tags: php, object, internal-server-error

Here is my code. I do not know why creating new object name site create an error. also the name of the file for my object is the same as the class name site.php.

```
<?php
class site {
    var $is_container_enabled = 1; 
    function init() {
        $this->container_tpl = "common/common";
    }
    function handle_page($page) {
        $this->cache_id = $page;
        $this->smarty->caching = 0;
        switch ($page) {
            case "static" :
                $type=$_REQUEST['choice'];
                $this->default_tpl = "static/$type";
                break;

            default :
                $this->is_container_enabled = isset($_REQUEST['ce'])?$_REQUEST['ce']:1;
                $this->default_tpl = $page.'/home';
                break;
        }
    }
    function is_container_enabled(){
        return $this->is_container_enabled;
    }
    function set_container_enabled($ce){
        $this->is_container_enabled = $ce;
    }
    function get_container_tpl(){
        return $this->container_tpl;
    }
}
```

some index.php that call the object site

```
  echo "before site declaration";
    $site = new site; // cause error
    echo "after site declaration";
            
    $site->init();
    $smarty = getSmarty();
    $site->smarty= &$smarty;
    $site->cache_id= &$cache_id;
```

[Result in the browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSUPn.jpg)

And here is also
[Console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leOpY.jpg)

Comment: try this:

 $site = new site();

Comment: Did you include the class file?

Comment: The reason is listed in `php_errors.log`. Check `php.ini` for its location. If it's not there (`php_errors.log` is not present or empty), make sure you put `error_reporting = E_ALL` in `php.ini` and restart your web server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer guys i will try this hope it will work. axiac there is no php.ini in my dream host server only phprc insite .php folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include 'site.php';
echo "before site declaration";
$site = new site; // You can access member variables/functions with this
echo "after site declaration";

$site->init();
$smarty = getSmarty();
$site->smarty= &$smarty;
$site->cache_id= &$cache_id;
```

Try this

Comment: Thank you so much include works i don't know why previously it work without include.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Quasimodo's clone mentions in the comments, you need to make sure that you are including the class in the file that you are trying to execute:

```
use site; // if you are using namespacing
include 'path/to/site'; // if you want to directly include the file
require 'path/to/site'; // same as include but will throw an E_COMPILE_ERROR if it wasn't found

echo "before site declaration";
$site = new site;
echo "after site declaration";
```

If it turns out you are already including the file then consider commenting out all of the methods in the `site` class and seeing if it still fails to instantiate. It could be that you have some syntax error in your class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer include works fine without the path

Comment: i think you need to place a / before and path just like /path/to/site

Comment: @JericBlank by including a `/` you are using the document root directory as the base of your file path. Excluding it makes the path relative to the file you are in. Which one you use is entirely up to you :)